# My Thread won't wake up

Tags: java, multithreading

EDITED: Added solutions from answers.

So I building the classic multi threaded program where 2 threads, a producer and consumer is reading from the same list. I did get it working my letting my consumer thread constantly poll the list, but this is inefficent and causes some other problems for me. So I thought I'd try out wait and notify instead. Both my threads are using the same buffer reference in the code below:

*Buffer:*

```
public class Buffer {

    private Queue<Character> result;

    public Buffer() {
        System.out.println("Buffer");
        result = new LinkedList<Character>();
    }

    public void addChar(char c) {
        result.add(c);
    }

    public char readChar() {
        return (char) result.remove();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return result.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

*Producer*

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {

private Buffer buffer;
private Callback callback;
private String input;

public Producer(Callback callback, Buffer buffer, String input) {
    this.callback = callback;
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.input = input;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("producer started");
       synchronized (buffer) {
            char[] array = input.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                buffer.addChar(array[i]);
                System.out.println("Adding--------- data");
                callback.returnData("Added " + array[i]);
                buffer.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Consumer*

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private Callback callback;
    private Buffer buffer;

    public Consumer(Callback callback, Buffer buffer) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("consumer started");
    try {
        synchronized (buffer) {
            while (true) {
                if (buffer.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Queue is empty ");
                    buffer.wait();
                }
                if (!buffer.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Reading data");
                    callback.returnData(" Retrieved " + String.valueOf(buffer.readChar()));
                } else {
                    callback.returnData("Waiting");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

What I want to do is each time the producer thread has added an element, it should notify my Consumer thread that it now can read from the buffer. The problem is that it doesn't wake up until all the data has been added. This is my result from the console:

```
buffer initiated
producer started
consumer started
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Adding--------- data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Reading data
Queue is empty
```

Now, what I really want is something like: "Adding Data", "Reading Data", "Adding Data" and so forth.

Comment: You have no lock protecting the buffer. What happens it the producer tries to add to the buffer at the same time as the consumer is removing from it?

Comment: @snickesnack, I missed a not sign `!`, I have edited the answer, please try now

Comment: You synchronized buffer for the whole iteration, which means you a blocking consumer until your `for` loop is finished. Instead you should sync on buffer inside `for` loop. Same applies to consumer, move `while` loop out of synchronized block. See my answer for example.

Comment: @snickesnack, I have added comment in my answer, try it as per discussion, I will update the code soon in my answer. Let us know it it works...

Comment: @snickesnack I have edited my code, hope it will be helpful...

Comment: @snickesnack, did not hear from you since I posted the edited code... please let us know if edited version is of help.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should synchronize on the shared object (call wait and notify on the buffer )

Check the below code -

```
class Producer implements Runnable {

    private Buffer buffer;
    private String input;

    public Producer(Buffer buffer, String input) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("producer started");
        char[] array = input.toCharArray();
        synchronized (buffer) {
            if (array.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    buffer.addChar(array[i]);
                    System.out.println("Adding--------- data");
                }
                buffer.notifyAll();

            } else {
                try {
                    System.out.println("producer waiting");
                    buffer.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            buffer.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private Buffer buffer;

    public Consumer(Buffer buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("consumer started");
        synchronized (buffer) {
            while (buffer.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("consumer waiting");
                try {
                    buffer.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            while (!buffer.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(buffer.readChar());
            }
            buffer.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but all it does is that first Producer adds all the items, And then the Consumer reads all the items, so really no point in having multiple threads. It should go something like the Producer adds data, then Consumer Reads, then Adds, then reads and so on.

Comment: @snickesnack Move the `for` loop outside the `synchronized` block. But don't expect to get any real, sensible behavior from toy code with a toy producer and a toy consumer. For toy code, it might really be best for the producer to add all the items at once, and so you can't blame the implementation for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `synchronized` block with the same object for which you wish to `wait` and `notify`. Simply putting `synchronized` keyword in method signature you are taking lock on `this` (current object) , but as you are invoking `wait` and `notify` on `buffer`, hence you need `synchronized` blocks on `buffer`.

You should put inside your method blocks as below, and remove `synchronized` keyword from methid signature.

```
synchronized (buffer) {
    // call notify ,( prefer notifyAll.) on buffer
}
```

and similar block for wait.

Below are the changes you can try,

```
public class Producer implements Runnable {
    private Buffer buffer;
    private Callback callback;
    private String input;

    public Producer(Callback callback, Buffer buffer, String input) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (buffer) {
            char[] array = input.toCharArray();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    buffer.addChar(array[i]);   // production done, 
                    // 1. now notify the consumer thread and 
                    // 2. wait till consumer consumes and notifies.
                    System.out.println("Adding--------- data");
                    callback.returnData("Added " + array[i]);
                    buffer.notifyAll();         // 1. notify done [ consumer notified , this will make consumer get awake from wait state and try to re aquire the lock]
                    buffer.wait();          //2. waiting for notification from consumer thread.
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private Callback callback;
    private Buffer buffer;

    public Consumer(Callback callback, Buffer buffer) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try { // having try catch outside will enable you to call interrupt on
                // the Thread to stop it
            synchronized (buffer) {
                // though we check for interrupt flag but in case thread is
                // interrupted while waiting, and InterruptedException is
                // thrown, the flag will be cleared, hence we need to put try
                // catch block outside, other option is to put it inside and make thread true again from catch block.
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    if (!buffer.isEmpty()) { 
                        System.out.println("Reading data");
                        callback.returnData(" Retrieved " + String.valueOf(buffer.readChar())); // consumption done, now
                                                                                                // 1. Notify the consumer thread
                                                                                                // 2. Wait till more production is done
                        buffer.notifyAll(); // 1. Consumer thread will get this notification and it will get in awakened state. It will try to aquire the lock on Buffer object.
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Queue is empty ");
                        callback.returnData("Waiting");
                    }
                    buffer.wait();      // 2. wait until more production is done and producer notifies after production
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The changes to the buffer need to be synchronized as well.

Comment: @David Schwartz please see , hopefully now answer is not incomplete n deserves to have that -1 removed :)

Comment: Can you add that to the code example, inside the `synchronized` block? Then I'll +1 you.

Comment: I added the code, but feel its the user of Buffer class to handle synchronization and hence no need to make methods of Buffer as synchronized, We already have synchronization in Producer and Consumer where buffer is being read and its state being changed so this much is sufficient.

Comment: `while (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {` I doubt that's right. Also, I'm not sure you want to call the callback while holding the lock. You should at least indicate that that's a choice.

Comment: oh i missed a ! sign ....@snickesnack you can try now. Callback code needs to be executed once buffer state is modified or is read, this is my assumption. I added same in comments :)

Comment: Ok, I tried your new code. Your assuumption is right, the consumer should be waken up each time something is added so that it can read. But I still have the same problem, all the data is added, then all data is read. It's like the call to "buffer.notifyAll();" doesn't execute after each run in the for loop in the Producer.

Comment: @snickesnack If that's not what you want, you shouldn't have coded your producer to loop over all the things it produces while holding the lock. Sure, `buffer.notifyAll()` executes and wakes threads, but the consumer can't do anything until the producer releases the lock.

Comment: @David Schwartz , thanks for the answers, your comments are really helpful. ,snickesnack If you need like that then once in a loop, char is added to buffer , you need to call notifyAll on buffer and then wait. Now once Consumer Thread will aquire the Lock, before it decides to wait it should call notifyAll on buffer object.

Comment: @nits.kk I don't see how that would work. If you call `notifyAll` on the buffer and then wait, what would the predicate be? What would you test in the `while` loop that wraps the wait call? It's sufficient to release the lock in-between production events.

Comment: @David Schwartz, if producer thread adds char to buffer (now the consumer thread is in waiting state on buffer), If now producer thread invokes notifyAll on buffer then, consumer thread gets awake and tries to fetch the lock, now if producer thread goes in wait state( by calling wait on buffer), it will release the lock and consumer thread will get chance to aquire the lock. After reading the buffer, the consumer thread can invoke the notifyAll on buffer and invoke wait on buffer. This way after using invoke notifyAll and then wait to let the other thread aquire the lock.

Comment: I Modified my answer... Hope this will be helpful

Comment: @nits.kk Right, I understand that's your thinking. And I explained why it won't work. "*what would the predicate be? What would you test in the while loop that wraps the wait call*" (you have to wait *for* something and you have to code in what that something is) and also why it's not necessary, "*It's sufficient to release the lock in-between production events*" (that will allow the other thread to get it if that makes sense).

Comment: @David Schwartz, hmm you are right but `buffer.wait()`  will release the lock, and thread is operating on buffer and since it has released the lock so it has nothing to do but wait until it is notified by some other thread who has acquired the lock. `wait` method (defined in Object.java) relinquishes the lock on the object... its the `sleep` method (defined in Thread.java) which waits but keep holding the lock.